# Map CSS width in cm or mm to desired pixels resolution?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div class="B">
    <div class="A">

    </div>
</div>
```

class A has width 2cm and heignt 2cm

where class B has width 200px and height 200px

No i want 4cm^2 of class A to occupy complete space of 200x200 px of class B. Is there any way of doing IT?

**EDIT**

i want to make A4 paper(in cm or mm or pts) in html and css . when user click preview button it should preview that paper in my desired pixels box div. thats what my actual scenario is. . . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web and physical units](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483955/web-and-physical-units)

Comment: i want a way to display 1cm with 20px on screen is it possible?????thats my simple question

Comment: Frankly, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can work with other values than pixels.

There you have a [Pixels To Centimeters Calculator](http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/pixels-x-to-centimeters-conversion.html), I hope it helps you.