# Responsive Printing in millimeters

Tags: css, printing

I am going to print from the browser to a receipt printer. I want to support 58mm --> full size paper using responsive design.  I used: http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/pixels-x-to-millimeters-conversion.html and it says 58 mm is approx. 219 pixels.

Is this an accurate way to measure pixels in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

That converter is misleading - it can produce only approximations (or at the very best, results that work for *your* specific display), but never generally accurate results.

The number of pixels per mm (or any other physical unit) will vary from display to display, as different displays will have a different number of differently sized pixels. See ["Pixel Density" in Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density)

You can specify physical measures in CSS and when printing they *should* come out OK if the browser and the printer driver are handling things right:

```
.mysheet { width: 19.2cm; height: 8cm; }
```

Some Browser/OS/display combinations (I don't know which protocols do this) apparently also can interpret physical measures and [render them in their correct size on screen.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023192)

Comment: How would I do this as responsive? I want this to work from 58mm --> 8.5 inches. Should I just do a bunch of media queries at different sizes?

Comment: @Chris I don't know what you mean by "as responsive" - the paper printout won't change sizes will it?

Comment: I need to support multiple sizes of paper.