# Why the `svg` size and the circle `stroke-width` are not like expected?

Tags: css, svg

Google Chrome 60.0.3112.90

I learn SVG. Why the `svg` *real* size is not *10cm x 10cm*, the circle `stroke-width` is not *1pt* and `radius` are not *2.5cm*?

```css
.svg-container, .canvas{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 10cm;
 height: 10cm;
 background-color: green;
}

.geometry {
 stroke: gray;
 fill: yellow;
 stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class='svg-container'>
  <svg class='canvas' viewBox='0 0 10 10'>
    <circle class='geometry' cx='5' cy='5'
      r='2.5'/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: [never trust the browser to generate true physical sizes specified in stylesheets on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023192/div-width-in-cm-inch).

Note that you have declared your viewBox to be `0 0 10 10`, meaning that it is 10 units across and 10 units tall. All the units applied to SVG elements within this will be rendered relative to the viewBox dimensions, i.e. a `stroke-width: 1px` on the circle will be rendered as 1/10 the width of the viewBox. Taking away the `viewBox` attribute will force things to be rendered in absolute pixels.

In the example below, I have set the svg width to `200px` for illustrative purposes. When `viewBox="0 0 10 10"` is used, all the units will be measured relative to this dimension:

- Stroke width of 1px will mean (200 ÷ 10) × 1 = 20px
- Radius of `2.5` will mean (200 ÷ 10) × 2.5 = 50px

Just remember that when `viewBox` it set, it controls how contents are set within its own coordinate system: and that is scaled up/down into actual pixels on the screen, depending on the width and height of the `<svg>` element. A better explanation is offered here: [svg viewBox attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335926/svg-viewbox-attribute)

```css
.svg-container, .canvas{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: green;
}

.geometry {
 stroke: gray;
 fill: yellow;
 stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class='svg-container'>
  <!-- Viewbox forces all units to be relative to its dimensions -->
  <svg class='canvas' viewBox='0 0 10 10'>
    <circle class='geometry' cx='5' cy='5'
      r='2.5'/>
  </svg>
</div>

<br />

<div class='svg-container'>
  <!-- Without viewbox, all units are rendered in px -->
  <svg class='canvas'>
    <circle class='geometry' cx='50' cy='50'
      r='25'/>
  </svg>
</div>
```