# how to show a long content in two html tags?

Tags: html, css, angular, md-card

I have an Angular4 app and in part of my page I have a `<md-card-content>` tag and I'm trying to show some content in a `<p>` tag and the `<p>` has 20 cm `max-height`!

It works for short contents but for longer contents it's not working! How can I create another `<md-card-content>` if the content's height become more than 20 cm? I wanna do something like Microsoft Word that moves to new page when the current page is full!

Here is some of my html code:

```
<md-card-content>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="mt-1">
          <div class="template">
            <p class="head">Mail Number: {{mail_number}}</p> <br>
            <p class="head">Date: {{created_at| date:'yyyy MMM dd'}}</p>
            <p class="inner" id="mail">{{content}}</p>
            <p class="sign" *ngIf="!pageFull">Sincerely</p><br>
            <p class="sign" *ngIf="!pageFull">{{sender}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </md-card-content>
```

This is my css:

```
.template{
  width: 600px;
  height: 1100px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-top: 23mm;
  padding-left: 2cm;
  padding-right: 2.5cm;
  //background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

p.head{
  line-height: 0.5px;
  padding-left: 120mm;
  font-size: 3;
}

p{
  line-height: 25px;
  word-spacing:1px;
}

.inner{
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 21mm;
  padding-bottom: 10mm;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  max-height: 20cm;
  width: 166mm;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

p.sign{
  padding-left: 10mm;
  line-height: 0.5px;
}
```

Comment: Using cm and mm in css is extremely unreliable, since [the result still depends on the correct reading of the monitor size by the operating system.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4023285/4011778)

Comment: @jrenk tnx for your information! i'll change them to px! but can you help me to solve my problem?

Comment: @fariba.j maybe yo ucould take a look at my answer  ?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set maximum heights on containers, then split your first paragrpah into words.

After that, you push word by word into your first paragraph, until the height of that paragraph becomes larger than the maximum height of your container. This will mean that the words following that will need to be pushed into the second paragraph.

Here is a working snippet, basic, but it gives you an idea :

```js
window.onload = function() {

  let p1 = document.getElementById('content-1');
  let words = p1.innerHTML.split(' ');
  let maxHeight = +document.getElementById('container-1').style.maxHeight.replace('px', '');
  p1.innerHTML = words[0];
  
  let index = -1;
  for(let i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    p1.innerHTML += ' ' + words[i];

    if(p1.clientHeight > maxHeight && index === -1) {
      index = i;
    }
  }

  let p2 = document.getElementById('content-2');
  let p2words = words.splice(index, words.length - index);
  p2.innerHTML = p2words.join(' ');
}
```

```css
#container-1, #container-2 {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

#content-1, #content-2 {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-1" style="max-height: 40px; overflow: hidden;">
  <p id="content-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nulla nisi, facilisis posuere lectus rhoncus, posuere interdum ante. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In vitae pulvinar justo, in rutrum enim. Vivamus rutrum turpis non ante molestie auctor. Pellentesque ipsum lacus, ultrices non risus sit amet, porttitor aliquam risus. Pellentesque sit amet ante vitae dolor commodo elementum. Nunc congue iaculis lectus, at tempor purus nullam.</p>
</div>
<div id="container-2">
  <p id="content-2"></p>
</div>
```

### EDIT Angular snippet

```js
@ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('contentOne') c1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('contentTwo') c2: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {

  let p1: HTMLElement = this.c1.nativeElement;
  let words = p1.innerHTML.split(' ');
  let maxHeight = (this.container.nativeElement as HTMLElement).style.maxHeight.replace('px', '');
  p1.innerHTML = words[0];
  
  let index = -1;
  for(let i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    p1.innerHTML += ' ' + words[i];

    if(p1.clientHeight > maxHeight && index === -1) {
      index = i;
    }
  }

  let p1: HTMLElement = this.c2.nativeElement;
  let p2words = words.splice(index, words.length - index);
  p2.innerHTML = p2words.join(' ');
}
```

```css
#container-1, #container-2 {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

#content-1, #content-2 {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div #container style="max-height: 40px; overflow: hidden;">
  <p #contentOne>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nulla nisi, facilisis posuere lectus rhoncus, posuere interdum ante. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In vitae pulvinar justo, in rutrum enim. Vivamus rutrum turpis non ante molestie auctor. Pellentesque ipsum lacus, ultrices non risus sit amet, porttitor aliquam risus. Pellentesque sit amet ante vitae dolor commodo elementum. Nunc congue iaculis lectus, at tempor purus nullam.</p>
</div>
<div id="container-2">
  <p #contentTwo></p>
</div>
```

Comment: So does this answer your issue ?

Comment: Be sure to use the same ids I used, or if not, rename them (this error means that `document.getElementById('content-2')` didn't found a tag with `id="content-2"`)

Comment: well i did'nt ptu the function in window.onload and i put it in ngOninit! and the error is can not set property of innerHtml of null for p2!

Comment: I put a snippet to show you it works, but in Angular, this isn't the same way of doing it ... Want me to make another snippet for Angular ?

Comment: Well I did it anyway :D Take a look, test it, and tell me if it works for you

Comment: No, I can't, that's exactly what I told you : I put a JS snippet to show you it works, and now you have an Angular snippet that only you can test.

Comment: what i did in my code was working and it splitted the text!but it didn't show the rest of the text in p2!and would you please explain a little about @viewchild and Elmentref

Comment: @ViewChild allows you to get HTML local variables available in your Typescript. ElementRef is the type of the variable returned by a ViewChild. I won't remake you a whole tutorial, those are the basics of Angular. Take a look at **[some online tutorials](http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/)** to grasp the concept !

Comment: tnx a lot!you really helped me!!

Comment: No problem, that's why I'm here :)

Comment: @ trichetriche  sorry i ask again!i used this codes and they are working!but it has problems in new paragraphs and it can not control it!and do you have any idea if i want to extend this for n new pages instead of only two pages?

Comment: Sure, take a look at the decorator @ViewChildren, this will allow you to handle n pages with a *ngFor !

Comment: and what about the paragraphs?do you have any idea?

Comment: As I said, take a look at this decorator, you will see that this applies to your paragraphs !